# Using the If formulae how do i make the true statement to be another formulae

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The basic syntax for IF statements is

```
=IF(A2,"A2 was true","A2 was false")
```

but for a particular cell in my sheet, if a condition is true, i would like that cell to be equal to a custom formulae some thing like

```
=IF(G2 = "hey", =NOW(),"No")
```

When cell G2 is equal to "hey", i would like the cell in to be have the current time and date but this returns an error.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(G2 = "hey", NOW(), "No")
```